# Dynamically set popover value with href on rollover in Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I need to made a popover show an iframe using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0, it popopver should show iframes based on values provided in links using the onmouseover event of href.

I got the first link working but not in 3.0, but in 2.0.2, but the second link is supposed to change the value of the variable  and show a different iframe and I don't seem to know how to do it.

```
$(window).load(function(){
var img = '<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="220" width="420"
                  src="http://dxlite.g7vjr.org/?dx=LU5DX&limit=10"></iframe>';
$("#blob").popover({title: 'Last 10 spots for the selected station', content: img});
})  

<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" style="margin-top:
100px">hover for popover</a>

<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" onmouseover=""var img =
'<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="220" width="420"
src="http://google.com"></iframe>';"" style="margin-top: 100px">hover for popover</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overcomplicating i believe.

- #1 You have duplicate id, you should assign unique id
- You have syntax errors. See the console.
- If you need to show bs popover on hover you just need to set the target in the bs popover settings or as a data-attribute.
- You need to show the iframe as context and not the html text rep of iframe so you need to set `data-trigger = "hover"` or in the settings.
- You need to inialte the popover or convert the object to popover by calling the constructor and the reason is stated in the document as below:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt in. If you would like to use them just specify a selector option.

- **[Demo BS 3](http://jsfiddle.net/KK398/)**
- **[Demo BS 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hmU8W/)**

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="blob" class="btn large primary" rel="popover" style="margin-top:
100px">hover for popover</a>

<a href="#" id="blob2" class="btn large primary" data-trigger="hover"  rel="popover" data-html="true" data-content='<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="220" width="420"
src="http://dxlite.g7vjr.org/?dx=LU5DX&limit=10"></iframe>' style="margin-top: 100px">hover for popover</a>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var img = '<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="220" width="420" src="http://dxlite.g7vjr.org/?dx=LU5DX&limit=10"></iframe>';
    $("#blob").popover({title: 'Last 10 spots for the selected station', content: img, html:true});
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover();
})
```

Comment: Thank you so very much PSL. You rock.

Comment: It works perfect. I'll post the link soon for you to see how I'm using it. Thanks much again.

Comment: Hi again PSL. Tested and it works as epxected with 3.0, but I have a couple of js files I load and the order in which I loaded the js code impacted the result.

Comment: Now the link to trigger the popover when it's inside a Google visualization chart of type table is not working. Can you please check at http://qsl.net/lu5dx/dxo/ and see what you find out. There are two links above the Wells div where some filters are placed. Those two work okay and trigger the popovers. However, inside of the google visualization you will see the text Tnx PSL! in the column IOTARef, that one is not working. The element has exactly the same syntax as the links you suggested. Maybe a listener is necessary to delay the draw of the table till all js is loaded?

Comment: @user1691233 Probably its a chart thing. I am not able to see the google visualization stuff?

Comment: Hi @PSL It could be a browser issue. I cannot see it in FF, but I do in Chrome, Opera and IE